# How can i open a form always in Edit mode , for a particular model

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-view

I have a model say 'my.attendance' , also have a form view for this which contains some attendance details.What i need is when i open this form view it should always open in Edit mode.So i can directly enter the attendance without clicking Edit button each time.

Comment: Welcome to SO, that is not a good question, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to extend the ViewManager to achieve this.

```
odoo.define('my_module.view_manager', function (require) {
"use strict";

var ViewManager = require('web.ViewManager');

ViewManager.include({

    custom_events: {

        execute_action: function(event) {
            var data = event.data;
            this.do_execute_action(data.action_data, data.env, data.on_closed)
                .then(data.on_success, data.on_fail);
        },
        search: function(event) {
            var d = event.data;
            _.extend(this.env, this._process_search_data(d.domains, d.contexts, d.groupbys));
            this.active_view.controller.reload(_.extend({offset: 0}, this.env));
        },
        switch_view: function(event) {
            if ('res_id' in event.data) {
                this.env.currentId = event.data.res_id;
            }
            var options = {};
            console.log(event.data)
            if (event.data.view_type === 'form' && !this.env.currentId) {
                options.mode = 'edit';
            } else if (event.data.mode) {
                options.mode = event.data.mode;
            }

            // Extra added code
            if (event.data.model){    
                if (event.data.model == 'my.model'){  // Checking the particular model.
                    options.mode = 'edit';
                }
            }


            this.switch_mode(event.data.view_type, options);
        },
        env_updated: function(event) {
            _.extend(this.env, event.data);
        },
        push_state: function(event) {
            this.do_push_state(event.data);
        },
        get_controller_context: '_onGetControllerContext',
        switch_to_previous_view: '_onSwitchToPreviousView',
    },

 });
});
```